# $f$ is twice differentiable, $f + 2 f^{'} + f^{''} \geq 0$ , prove the following

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Let $ f : [0,1] \rightarrow R$. $f$ is twice diff.
 and $f(0) = f(1) = 0$

If
 $f + 2 f^{'} + f^{''} \ge 0$ , prove that $f\le 0$ in the domain.

Please don’t give complete solution, only hints.

Comment: @MathFacts if $f(x)=e^{\lambda x}$, then $f(0),f(1)\neq0$.

Comment: Have you read the question fully? f(x) can't ever be  of the form $e^{x}$

Comment: Can you solve $g+2g'+g'' = 0$, $g(0)=g(1)=0$?

Comment: @LucyferZedd Where did you get this problem from?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hint** Let $g(x)=f(x)e^x$. Then 
$$g''=(f+2f'+f'')e^x \geq 0 \,.$$

That means that $g$ is....
How does this solve the problem?

Comment: Quite clever indeed.

Comment: very nice solution

Comment: Wait, so $g$ is concave up and has roots at $0$ and $1$, which means that in $(0, 1)$, $g$ is nonpositive, which forces $f$ to be nonpositive there...but how can you conclude $f$ is nonpositive everywhere?

Comment: @Nishant everywhere... where? The domain of $f$ is $[0,1]$.

Comment: Oh wow, I forgot to read the entire question...

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** If not, $f$ must have a maximum in the interior of the interval.